# center logo in table foundation framework

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I recently started using the foundation framework with email newsletters. As I can see I have to go back to the good old tables. I cannot understand why I have so big problems of centering/align a logo?

The logo is keep hanging to the left, instead of center. I have set a border on the tables so it is eaiser to see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>A title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-emails.css" />

<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <style> -->
  <table class="body" data-made-with-foundation>
    <tr>
      <td class="float-center" align="center" valign="top" style="border: 1px solid pink">
        <center>
          <table class="container" align="center" style="border: 1px solid green">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table class="row">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <img src="https://i1.wp.com/1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/line-art-logo.jpg?fit=600%2C400&resize=350%2C200" style="border:1px solid red" align="center">
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after 2 hours searcing I found the answer here:

https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/alignment.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your document (!DOCTYPE) IS NOT **XHTML**. You need to use *transitional* or *HTML*

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

---

After that, you need:

```
<img src="https://i1.wp.com/1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/line-art-logo.jpg?fit=600%2C400&resize=350%2C200" style="border:1px solid red; margin: 0 auto;">
```

`align="center"` **is NOT** a valid HTML5 property, it is valid in HTML4+